# Add a nginx location directive for react hash routes

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I am trying to reverse proxy a react based app with another location on the same server, When I add a location containing '#'(react hash routing) it get ignored the location get ignored because of starting with hash. The below is my server conf

```
location / {
  return 301 /#/target;
}
location /#/target {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000
}
```

Because of the the hash based routes it get ignored and matched with the location '/' and ends in a indefinite loop

```
location / {
  return 301 /target;
}
location /target {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8000
}
```

The above works. Is there a way to escape the hash? I tried with double quotes.

Comment: The server never sees the part of the URL from the `#` onwards. It is entirely handled client side.

Comment: So is there any work around?

Comment: Can you share me any docs regarding this

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant - rfc 2396 section 4.1 - Fragment Identifier "is not part of a URI".